# Way to get high voltage from a watch battery

Tags: voltage, batteries, transformer

I'm creating a vary small device that need an high voltage around 50v. But because the device is really small like a pistol bullet, I can only use very small batteries like watch battery or button cell. But I cant use Transformer, also because of the size limitation.

Is there any other way to do that (may be electronically). But the solution need to be small as much as possible and the light weight as much as possible.

Appropriate your helps

Comment: What amount of current do you need, remember you could use boost converter for your need. :)

Comment: This is for generate static field, So doesn't matter of the current. Only need as much as voltage.

Comment: Try these boost regulator: MAX863, MAX1771

Comment: A transformer needn't be much bigger than an inductor so in order to answer this question (with this bizarre constraint), you should specify a space envelope and not state "small as much as possible".

Comment: @Andy: MY device is cylindrical. height is 3 cm and diameter is  7mm. So  watch battery and the whatever device I'm looking for here, should be fit in to this scale.

Comment: A product or a one off thing? You might be able to construct a ratsnests cockroft walton from small smd components

Comment: Boost converter with small inductor will work if current needed is ~ zero.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be with a boost converter, but the size depends on which Boost Converter IC you use, so you may want to search on mouser, digikey, farnell etc.